# custom pop up menu like this image

Tags: android

How can i make a custom pop up menu something like this in android ! Iam developing a reader application , suggest me something !

Check this out please :
http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/image158.png?56dd13

Something same like this ! in android Play Books App also we have the same thing , i want to develop this in android , how can i make it and i want that in my action bar .

Comment: Have you tried something? E.g. DialogFragment?

Comment: Yes ! i have used alert dialog ! but i want a perfect procedure to make this , same like the google play books drop down menu !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may help you, create simple layout xml having same view as per your requirement and and use these Activity Theme as Dialog so it appears just you want.
But Please make sure you make it's Layout width and height as **wrap_content not match_content or fill_content**.